# Нахождение траектории отражения пули для ИИ (Unity)

Tags: c#, математика, разработка-игр, unity3d-android, вектор

Суть такая: есть игра, в которой каждый выпущенный снаряд отражает от поверхности n раз. Проблема: найти метод которым можно заставить ИИ стрелять в нужном направлении, чтобы снаряд летел в позицию игрока. [image: Найти нужно именно синие линии]

Проблемы с наведением ИИ в сторону игрока (зеленая линия) нет, проблем с отражением самой пули тоже нет. Есдинственная проблема - алгоритм нахождения нужной точки, в которую нужно выстрелить, чтобы отраженный снаряд попал в игрока. Единственный вариант который я вижу на данный момент - заранее сделать Raycast вокруг обьекта ИИ, отразить лучи от поверхности и вернуть только те, что после отражения попали в игрока. Но такая реализация кажется мне слишком нагруженной, тем более для мобильных устройств. Возможно существует более оптимальный метод для таких рассчетов, или у вас есть идеи лучше, буду очень признателен

Comment: Попробуй подойти к этой задаче с другой точки зрения. отзеркаливание луча аналогично прохождению прямого луча через  точно такое же, но отзеркаленное пространство.

Comment: Щас я на листочке попробую отобразить алгоритм

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй подойти к этой задаче с другой точки зрения:
отражающийся луч это по сути луч, который проходит через точно такой же, но зеркальный мир. Думаю по данной картинки всё будет понятно
[image: иллюстрация работы алгоритма]
Проверяете где луч не встречает препятствия и всё.
Если хотите увеличить максимальное количество отражений, то можете увеличить количество отражений мира

**UPDATE:**

Значит получается такой алгоритм:

- проходимся для каждой стенки
- Если эта стенка не находится между целью и пушкой (другими словами: если при проведении линии между пушкой и целью она не пересекается с текущей стеной) то
- Отзеркаливаем позицию цели относительно текущей стенки
- измеряем угол между пушкой и целью.
- пускаем этот луч и проверяем, не сталкивается ли он с какой либо стеной
  Полученный массив углов будет являться набором всех возможных вариантов при одном отражении. Если нам надо больше отражений, то на каждое отзеркаливание позиции цели нам надо ее еще раз отзеркаливать относительно стенок, которые мы тоже должны отзеркалить
  Звучит сложно, но надеюсь понятно)

Comment: Кстати вопрос довольно интересный, и в какой то степени сложный, но решение мне в голову пришло практически мгновенно (чему я кстати удивлён), хотя возможно эта задача мне так легко далась только потому, что я видел видео где для решении другой задачи использовался подобный метод

Comment: Очень интересный подход. Спасибо вам огромное, это очень сильно поможет, разве что у меня пока не сложилась полная картинка в голове и нету точного представления подобного в коде. Но в целом это лишь немного векторной математики. Единственный момент что в игре коллизия обрабатывается со всеми препятствиями, и на вашей схеме единственный вариант, который  ИИ в моей игре посчитает нужным - это правое отражение. Но это лишь мелочи конкретно моей реализации, спасибо вам большое

Comment: Кстати, может можно заценить видео где использовался этот метод? Только в целях интереса

Comment: То самое видео: https://youtu.be/XYupMsNQ6KM

Comment: Единственный минус такого метода (который я только что заметил) в том, что работает он только для квадратных комнат, а для отражения от внутренних стен не учитывается. Думаю все же можно как то доработать этот алгоритм, завтра еще попробую кое что поделать

Comment: Пока что у меня имеется вариант отражать весь мир относительно каждой стороны. Хм... Тогда этот алгоритм еще легче. Мы можем перемещать врага относительно каждой из сторон, а дальше просто вычислять угол между врагом и источником выстрела. Завтра я попробую написать псевдокод этого алгоритма

Comment: Обновил пост, теперь имеется более четкий алгоритм

Comment: У меня все же появилось понимание всей картины и я думаю что метод рабочий, и даже более того, может быть несколько упрощен.
1 - Упростить себе задачу и оставить только 2  столкновения: одно со стеной, второе уже с игроком или другим препятствием, которое в конечном итоге уничтожит обьект
2 - Принебречь столкновением со внешними стенами, однако записать точку столкновения.
3 - То, что метод работает только для квадратных комнат - не проблема. ИИ имеет окружность как зону видимости. В случае попадания в нее игрока можно брать диаметр окружности

Comment: ... в качестве стороны квадрата, помещать ее в центр игрового поля и брать в расчет только те обьекты, что попали в кдварат. 
5 - т.к. отражает не только игрок и враг, а еще и другие обьекты, в случае пересечения луча с отзеркаленным обьектом и его отражения в игрока - записывать это как возможный вариант. Тоже звучит достаточно сложно, сейчас схематично набросаю

Answer (score 2):

В целом алгоритм практически готов, благодаря предложеному методу. Единственная моя доработка для включения коллизии внутренних стен - считать отраженные лучи отзеркаленных обьектов. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть, если зеркальная копия, направляя луч в оригинального персонажа лучом попала во внутреннюю стену и отразилась в зеркальную копию персонажа - считать это успешным вариантом. Внешние же стены отражать луч, выпущенный зеркальной копией не будут, однако, в случае пересечения луча с персонажем точка пересечения луча с внешней стеной будет считаться отправной точкой для оригинального кастера луча.Огромное спасибо за готовый алгоритм, как оказалось, канал я ваш знаю и даже подписан)

**UPD**

Для лучшего понимания:

центральная картинка - оригинал

синий пунктирный луч - направление зеркальной копии к оригинальному игроку

зеленый пунктир - отраженный луч зеркальной копии

Comment: Канал не мой) но интересный

Comment: В любом случае спасибо за готовый алгоритм, очень сильно помогли)